# Css. Скачет hover

Tags: css, анимация, transition

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align:center
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}

div:hover {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 4px solid #ddd;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>HELLO</div>
  <div>HELLO</div>
  <div>HELLO</div>
  <div>HELLO</div>
</section>
```

**Проблемы 2:**

1. При наведении блок скачет.
2. При наведении transition увеличивает Border с 0px до 3px, а хотелось бы чтобы увеличения не было, а плавно появлялся только border c 3px.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например задать изначальный прозрачный `border`:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align:center
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}

div:hover {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 4px solid #ddd;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>HELLO</div>
  <div>HELLO</div>
  <div>HELLO</div>
  <div>HELLO</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 5):

Еще как вариант - использовать `bоx-shadow`

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align:center
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}

div:hover {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #ddd;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>HELLO</div>
  <div>HELLO</div>
  <div>HELLO</div>
  <div>HELLO</div>
</section>
```